Activate non-active window by clicking the mouse wheel
I want to be able to make a non-active window active via mouse wheel click instead of having to left-click inside the window.
Useful when using CAD and switching back and forth between necessary apps.
Left-clicking in CAD (BricsCAD in this case) will make the window active but it will also click and selects an entity or creates a selection window immediately, which isn't desirable.
So, how can I use a middle click (or similar) to activate a window?

This means that BricsCAD doesn't follow Apple's Human Interface Guidelines (HIG).
What you're looking for is called "focus follows mouse", maybe the AutoRaise app will do what you need. You can find more details in this StackOverflow question.
